# Powershell Create AD Accounts from CSV - Copy User Issue

Tags: powershell

I have put together a script to create new user accounts in AD from a CSV File but I'm having a few issues with the copy user part. So it works when every new user has a copy user but when they don't provide a copy user and they leave this blank it's failing to create the variable and using the copy user variable from the previous row. Any ideas how I could amend this to only run the copy user part if the copy user cell is filled in on the csv file?

```
$ADUsers = Import-Csv "C:\Bulk Create New Users\New Users.csv"
ForEach ($User in $ADUsers)
{
    $Server = "DomainController"
    $FirstName = $User.FirstName
    $Surname = $User.Surname
    $ExtraCharacter = $User.ExtraCharacter
    $EmailSuffix = $User.EmailSuffix
    $BusinessUnit = $User.BusinessUnit
    $JobTitle = $User.JobTitle
    $Description = $User.Description
    $Company = $User.Company
    $Office = $User.Office
    $OU = $User.OU
    $Password = $User.Password
    $CopyUser = Get-ADUser -Identity $User.CopyUser -Properties MemberOf
    $IntranetGroup = $User.IntranetGroup
    $DisplayName = $User.DisplayName
    $Username = $User.Username
    $Email = $User.Email
    New-ADUser -Server $Server -Name $DisplayName -AccountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $Password -Force) -Company $Company -Description $Description -DisplayName $DisplayName -EmailAddress $Email -Enabled $True -GivenName $FirstName -Office $Office -OtherAttributes @{'extensionAttribute10'=$Email;'mailNickname'=$Username} -Path $OU -SamAccountName $Username -Surname $Surname -Title $JobTitle -UserPrincipalName $Email
    Set-ADUser -Server $Server -Identity $Username -Add @{proxyAddresses ="SMTP:" + $Email}
    Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Server $Server -Identity $Username -MemberOf "Standard","Member","Groups"
```

`#Copy membership groups from the copy user to the new user & then remove the Equitrac group

$CopyToNewUser = Get-ADUser -Server $Server -Identity $UserName -Properties MemberOf
$CopyUser.MemberOf | Where-Object {$CopyToNewUser.MemberOf -notcontains $_} | Add-ADGroupMember -Server $Server -Members $CopyToNewUser
Remove-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Server $Server -Identity $UserName -MemberOf "Equitrac Print Users" -Confirm:$False}`

Comment: Instead of copying the csv data into intermediate variables, you should read about [splatting](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-5.1) to simplify/streamline your foreach. also check 1st if there ***IS*** a copyuser and if not [continue](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_continue?view=powershell-5.1) to the next.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and the link on splatting, will have a read up on it. How would you get Powershell to check if there is a copy user? That's the part I was struggling with, couldn't find anything helpful when searching.

Answer (score 0):

1. check if the property `.CopyUser` is empty
2. check if `Get-ADUser` did return something for `$User.CopyUser`

```
$ADUsers = Import-Csv "C:\Bulk Create New Users\New Users.csv"
ForEach ($User in ($ADUsers|Where {$_.CopyUser -ne ''}) ) {
   if(!($CopyUser = Get-ADUser -Identity $User.CopyUser -Properties MemberOf)){continue}
   ...
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't that first point completely skip creating that user if the copy user was empty? I'd only want it to skip copying the membership groups.

Comment: Well, I did (mis-)understood you that way. But you can insert an if inside the foreach at any point to conditionally execute code parts.